# how to edit DialogBox text

Tags: java, android

I want to change the text next to the checkbox in the dialog box.

[image: here is a picture explaining which text i want to change]

```
package com.codingdemos.customdialogcheckbox;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_app_updates, null);
        CheckBox mCheckBox = mView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        mBuilder.setTitle("What's new in V1.0");
        mBuilder.setMessage("1- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \n2- consectetur adipiscing elit. \n3- Vestibulum vulputate fringilla justo. \n4- nec varius magna suscipit ac.");
        mBuilder.setView(mView);
        mBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder.create();
        mDialog.show();
        mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(compoundButton.isChecked()){
                    storeDialogStatus(true);
                }else{
                    storeDialogStatus(false);
                }
            }
        });

        if(getDialogStatus()){
            mDialog.hide();
        }else{
            mDialog.show();
        }
    }

    private void storeDialogStatus(boolean isChecked){
        SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CheckItem", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        mEditor.putBoolean("item", isChecked);
        mEditor.apply();
    }

    private boolean getDialogStatus(){
        SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CheckItem", MODE_PRIVATE);
        return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean("item", false);
    }
}
```

I want to change the text that says "**Don't show this message again**" to "I agree with Terms and Conditions"

Comment: by using mCheckBox.setText property you can change the text

Comment: @KarishmaPatel  can you post a sample code. got an error when adding CheckBox.setText("Hello");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Just add

> mCheckBox.setText(" I agree with Terms and Conditions");

```
mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(compoundButton.isChecked()){
                    storeDialogStatus(true);
                }else{
                    storeDialogStatus(false);
                }
            }
        });

        if(getDialogStatus()){
            mDialog.hide();
        }else{
            mDialog.show();
        }
    }
```